# A recursive program to help calculate two values in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I need some help with a program for my programming class. It's a recursive program that takes a subtotal and a gratuity rate given by the user that outputs the full total and the gratuity cost. This is what I've got so far, and for some reason it just doesn't work:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.until.Scanner;
public class gratuity {
    private double total;
    private double subTotal;
    private double gratRate;
    private double newSubTotal;
    private double newGratRate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter the subtotal: ");
        System.out.print("Enter the gratuity rate: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double subtotal = scan.nextDouble();
        double gratRate = myScan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("The Gratuity is: " + newSubtotal);
        System.out.println("The Total is: " + Total);
    }

    public static double computeGratRate() {
        double newGratRate = (gratRate/100);
        return newGratRAte;
    }

    public static double computeNewSub() {
        double newSubTotal - (subTotal * newGratRate);
        return newSubTotal;
    }

    public static double computeTotal() {
        double total = (newSubTotal + newGratRate);
        return total;
    }
}
```

If anyone would help me figure out how to fix it, I would be very grateful! Thank you!

Comment: For starter, there are at least two compile errors in your program.  Did you mistype your program into SO?

Comment: Also, you mention that your program is recursive.  But I don't see anything that suggests recursion (e.g. a method that calls itself).

Comment: That may be why I'm having problems. Recursion just isn't my strong suit truth be told, so I tend to have trouble actually implementing it at times. I've tried to learn how to do it properly, but it just has a hard time sinking in sometimes, you know?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

You are creating new variables called "subtotal" and "gratRate" in Main.  These values override the member variables of the class.

Your problem won't compile anyway, because...

All your methods are static, which is OK, but these static methods are accessing non-static variables.  Make all your member variables of this class static.  (Or make everything outside of Main not static and then have "Main" be a stub to just create an instance of the gratuity class.

You need to import `java.util.Scanner`, not `java.until.Scanner`.

This line is a compiler error:

```
double newSubTotal - (subTotal * newGratRate);
```

I think you mean:

```
double newSubTotal = (subTotal * newGratRate);
```

That should be enough hints for now.... keep trying.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be sure to keep this in mind. Btw, that thing with the import was simply a typo from when I was typing the code on here. Thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Gratuity {
    private double subTotal;
    private double gratRate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Gratuity gratuity = new Gratuity();

        System.out.print("Enter the subtotal: ");        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        gratuity.setSubTotal(scan.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter the gratuity rate: ");
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        gratuity.setGratRate(myScan.nextDouble());

        System.out.println("The new GratRate is: " + gratuity.getNewGratRate());
        System.out.println("The New Sub is: " + gratuity.getNewSub());
        System.out.println("The Total is: " + gratuity.getTotal());
    }

    public double getNewGratRate() {
        return gratRate/100;
    }
    public double getNewSub() {
        return getNewGratRate() * subTotal;
    }
    public double getTotal() {
        return getNewSub() + getNewGratRate();
    }

    public double getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal;
    }
    public void setSubTotal(double subTotal) {
        this.subTotal = subTotal;
    }
    public double getGratRate() {
        return gratRate;
    }
    public void setGratRate(double gratRate) {
        this.gratRate = gratRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't do student's homework for them!  That's not what SO is about!

Comment: @selbie: OK. I will not do it next time. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Don't worry, I actually compiled this to see if it would actually work, and while it does it doesn't achieve the exact result that I am looking for. It did put me closer towards being on the right track though, thank you!